# black screen after upgrading from 14.04 to 15.10?

Tags: 14.04, 15.10

I know my upgradation didnt go properly there were many errors
After i tried to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10, only console comes after the ubuntu icon. When i try to back from the console, only a black screen appears. I have tried some commands

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a

but nothing has happened, it shows some unmet dependencies
 I have tried upgrading more than two times this month and everytime due to issues i have to go back to the factory settings of 14.04
I dont have a extenal graphic card, the normal intel graphic 
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Maybe put 16.04 on your system. I had problems as well with the upgrade from 14.04. I had to do a fresh install. Be sure to back your personal folders up! Mega-sync works great and its 50GB.  [Mega-sync](https://mega.nz/#sync!linux) and be sure to get the browser add-on

Comment: I tried your command, but it show something like, the following packages have unmet dependencies: